# Phonegap (build) aap sync with remote DB and Files

Tags: caching, cordova, synchronization

The situation is as follows. I am developing an app for touristical info from a few towns. The customer wants to be able to update the app database by a web content admin. I have managed to update sqlite local DB with the remote DB contents but I am having some more difficulties when downloading images.

I can download images, the problem is, when updating remote images (here it is important to say that they all have the same name: "list_img.jpg" or "detail_img.jpg" changing the directory where they are stored) it seems that the app (or maybe the server) has it in a cache so it does not download the newest image but a previous version.

I am right?If so, how can I avoid this caching?

I would also like to know whether anyone knows a way to check the sqlite local contents in the device. I can control it in chrome but it is a little tricky for me to retrieve the contents in the phone DB (alerts and so on).

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already tried this to get your data?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: yoururl,
        type: 'GET',
        data: yourdata,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            //Do stuff
        }
    })
```

Comment: I tried it but finally I decided to use a suffix (unix date) for the image names and keep track of the previous img so I copied the former and deleted the latter. Anyway it is good to know how to deal with these situations when using jquery. Thanks!!